# Google Adwords API call to download data through C#

Tags: c#, google-ads-api

I am working on some C# project to make API calls to **Adwords** to download data.

I have already get the access token by using:

```
WebRequest webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin");
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        string postParams =

            "accountType=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("GOOGLE") +
            "&Email=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("xxxx@xxxx.com") +
            "&Passwd=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("xxxx") +
            "&service=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("adwords") +
            "&source=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", "sample1",
                "sample2", "1"));

        byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postParams);
        webRequest.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;

        using (Stream strmReq = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            strmReq.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
        }

        string retVal = "";
        try
        {
            WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse();

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string sResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
                string[] splits = sResponse.Split('\n');
                foreach (string split in splits)
                {
                    string[] subsplits = split.Split('=');
                    if (subsplits.Length >= 2 && subsplits[0] == "Auth")
                    {
                        retVal = subsplits[1];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Could not generate auth token.", ex);
        }
```

I would appreciate if someone can let me know what is the next step to make an API call to download data. https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/reporting

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the client library? https://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-dotnet/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Jon mentions about using the client library, you should also check out the examples directory of the download, specifically the [reporting example](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-dotnet/source/browse/trunk/examples/adwords/csharp/v201209/Reporting/DownloadCriteriaReport.cs), and also the [XML Schema for the report definition](https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/reportdownload/v201209/reportDefinition.xsd) to modify the example for your specific requirements.